# safe template tag in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-grappelli

I am using django-grappelli as django admin template. But I want to use `{{foo|safe}}` for a particular entry from my database which I made using CKeditor, which is being displayed in admin template. I know how to use safe tag in templates but I don't to how to use them in admin site.I want to apply `safe` tag to Bio field .Thanks.

[image: Screen shot of Feild]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a new field, which would use `mark_safe`:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class ExampleModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    base_model = ExampleModel
    list_display = (..., 'enter_bio_safe')

    def enter_bio_safe(self, obj):
        return mark_safe(obj.enter_bio)
    enter_bio_safe.short_description = 'Enter bio'
```

Comment: Should be `list_display`, not `fields`.

Comment: yeah it worked after update.Can you explain this code?